# Run a parallel command while waiting for ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to ssh into a server and check for a service to see if it is up and running. What i do is to use ssh and run a command which calls that service and check the output of that command.
I want to have a progress bar to show the user that the script is trying to check the status of the service; but I am not able to run the progress bar function while ssh command is not returned from the server! (ssh must wait for the service to fully start before it can check the status) and I miss that part of the progress.

Is there a standard way to deal with such a scenario?

My ssh command is something like this:

```
State=$(ssh host "app-status")
```

And it should return something like:

```
Status OK
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `ssh` in the background and have it write its output to a FIFO

```
#! /bin/bash
mkfifo fifo-ssh
(ssh host "app-status"; echo error;) >fifo-ssh &
exec 3<>fifo-ssh
until read -t 1 -u 3 status; do
  echo -n .
done
# if [ "$status" = error ]; then...
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternative to Hauke's that doesn't involve creating a named pipe (and the hassle associated with exclusive access, cleanup... of it), that preserves the exit status, and supports multi-line output:

```
result=$(
  {
    {
      ssh host app-status >&3 3>&-; echo "$?"
    } | {
      until read -t1 ret; do
        printf . >&2
      done
      exit "$ret"
    }
  } 3>&1
)
```

should work in `zsh`, `ksh93` and `bash` (`$status` is special (an alias for `$?`) in `zsh` like in `(t)csh`).

Above, we've got a subshell (`{ ssh ...; echo "$?"; }`) whose output goes to the `until` loop. Nothing is output by that subshell except the `$?` when `ssh` returns. `ssh` output itself goes to `$result` by way of file descriptor 3 which we've made to point to the pipe that feeds the command substitution.

So, while `ssh` is running, the `read -t1` will timeout, and as soon as `ssh` returns, `read` will read the exit status and finish the loop.

More detailed explanation at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113831/22565) that's a follow up on this one.

Comment: just trying to understand. First `3>&1` fd 3 is opened as a dup of stdout. ssh stdout is set to dup of fd3, then 3 is closed `3>&-` stdout from ssh is piped into read loop, which is printed to stderr `>&2` Nothing is run in background, so how does this help?

Comment: @XTian, no, see my edit. The fd 3 is only used to carry the original stdout within that command substitution to `ssh`. The _progress loop_ reads nothing until `ssh` exits.

Comment: I've opened this up as a new question to avoid clogging this one with comments.

Comment: OP's new question: [Please help explain this bash output redirection](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113831)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is much simpler to run the progress bar in the background instead of the ssh command. Something like this:

```
function progress {
while :
do
    sleep 1
    echo -e ".\c"
done
}

progress &

PROGRESS_PID=$!

ssh_command_runs_here

status_check_command_here

kill -9 $PROGRESS_PID
```

Comment: Whether that works depends on the `stty tostop` setting.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Can you explain more?

Comment: "Background processes which attempt to read from (write to when stty tostop is in effect) the terminal are sent a SIGTTIN (SIGTTOU) signal by the kernel's terminal driver, which, unless caught, suspends the process."

Comment: Maybe you should find a progress indicator that will die when `SIGTERM`ed or `SIGINT`ed.

Comment: I have a problem; when i kill the script (Ctrl-C) while progressing, the dots continue to print on the screen!