# Please help explain this bash output redirection

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe, file-descriptors

This script was posted as answer to a [Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113812/run-a-parallel-command-while-waiting-for-ssh/113822?noredirect=1#comment176211_113822).
And I'm trying to work out what's going on.

```
result=$(
  {
    {
      ssh host app-status >&3 3>&-; echo "$?"
    } | {
      until read -t1 ret; do
        printf . >&2
      done
      exit "$ret"
    }
  } 3>&1
)
```

Here's my explanation, but I'm sure it's wrong.

1. The outer `{...} 3>&1` : fd 3 is opened as a duplicate of stdout
2. Then second half of pipe, '| { }` no redirection
3. In read loop printf's stdout is duplicated with stderr, so in 2. (above) all output actually comes via stderr.
4. Now the first half of pipe, `{ ssh ... } |` : stdout of ssh is dupped onto fd3 (which is in fact stdout from 1. fd 3 is closed with `3>&-` so stdout is re-opened onto what it was originally and this is piped into 2.
5. finally, `echo` just prints to stdout

So my question (problem with understanding) is; Is the result of this the same as just printf to stderr ? What does the *voodo* redirect to 3 actually achieve?
Is there anything asynchronous in here ?

Comment: See also [File descriptors & shell scripting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting), [How to grep standard error stream (stderr)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-grep-standard-error-stream-stderr/3540#3540), [When would you use an additional file descriptor?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor/18904#18904)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can get this script to fail on my version of cygwin with errors like `exit: : numeric argument required` or `read: read error: 0: Permission denied` followed by an infinite series of dots, depending on how app-status behaves on the remote side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `$(...)`, stdout (fd 1) is a pipe. At the other end of the pipe, the shell reads the output and stores it into the `$result` variable.

With: `$({ blah; } 3>&1)` we make it that both fd 3 and 1 point to that pipe in `blah`.

`blah` is `cmd1 | cmd2`. There `cmd1` and `cmd2` are started concurrently with `cmd1` fd 1 pointing to another pipe (the one to `cmd2`), however we don't want `ssh` output to go to that pipe, we want it to go to the first pipe so that it can be stored in `$result`.

So we have `{ ssh >&3; echo "$?"; } | cmd2`, so that only the `echo` output goes to the pipe to `cmd2`. `ssh` output (fd 1) goes to `$result`. `ssh` not needing a fd 3, we close it for it after we've used it to set fd 1 (`3>&-`).

`cmd2`'s input (fd 0) is the second pipe. Nothing is writing to that pipe (since `ssh` is writing to the first pipe) until `ssh` terminates and `echo` outputs the exit status there.

So in `cmd2` (being the `until` loop), the `read -t1` is actually waiting with timeout until `ssh` exits. After which, `read` will return successfully with the content of `$?` fed by `echo`.

Comment: Argh! I see, ssh does go to original stdput and produces result which is what you want, and nothing is sent through pipe by ssh, only the `echo $?` of ssh. :-) very clever ! I like the read loop timeout too. tks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, firstly what happens if you execute a remote command via ssh

```
ssh  otherhost /bin/true; echo $?
0
```

and

```
ssh otherhost /bin/false; echo $?
1
```

so `echo "$?"` prints the return value of `app-status` to stdout (file handle 1)

1. The outer `{...} 3>&1` redirects all input from file handle 3 to stdout
2. `>&3 3>&-` redirects stdout to file handle 3 and closes file handle 3.
3. `read -t1 ret` reads input from stdin to variable `ret`
4. `printf . >&2` prints `.` to stderr (file handle 2)

Good read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea behind the *voodo* redirections of fd 3 to fd 1 and fd 1 to fd 3 in the group command `{ ... 1>&3 3>&- ...} 3>&- 3>&1` is to make the output of the `ssh` command bypass the `ssh | until` pipe via fd 3.

Anything written to fd 3 inside the group command with `1>&3` will get around the pipe mechanism.

This way the `read` command (which will "return failure if a complete line of input is not read within TIMEOUT seconds", see `help read` in bash) will only get to read the exit status of the `ssh` command and the output assigned to the `result` variable can be restricted to the output of the `ssh` command.

```
# examples for bypassing a pipe using output redirections

# cf. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18711
echo hello | sed 's/hello/HELLO/'
{ echo hello 1>&3 3>&- | sed 's/hello/HELLO/'; } 3>&- 3>&1

{
result=$(
  {
    {
      ssh localhost 'sleep 5; echo "ssh output"; exit 55' >&3 3>&-; echo "$?"
    } | {
      until read -t1 ret; do
        printf . >&2
      done
      printf '\n%s\n' "exit $ret" >&2
      exit "$ret"
    }
  } 3>&1
)
echo "result: $result"
}

# output:
# .....
# exit 55
# result: ssh output
```

And, last but not least, duplicating a stdout stream is done by `man 1 tee`, not by output redirections.
The outer `{...} 3>&1` redirection means that fd 3 is opened and points to where fd 1 is pointing to, i. e. to stdout.

Further reading:

- [File Descriptor 101](http://www.runscripts.com/support/guides/scripting/bash/redirecting-stdout-stderr/successfully-redirecting-stdout-stderr/file-descriptor-101)
- [Why does redirection + pipe ( 2>&1 |) merge both streams instead of moving stderr to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6479741)